# Prove that a set of strings contains a string of $n$ zeroes for every integer $n \geq$ 12 by strong induction

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

### Context

I am currently working on a strong induction proof involving strings. I am trying to prove the following:

Let $0^n$ mean a string of $n$ zeros. Let $S$ be the set of strings defined as follows:

$\textbf{Basis Steps:}$ $0^3 \in S$, $0^5 \in S$

$\textbf{Recursive Step:}$ If $0^x, 0^y \in S$ then $0^x \cdot 0^y \in S$ where $\cdot$ is string concatenation.

Show that, for every integer $n\geq 12$ the set $S$ contains the string $0^n$.

### My attempt to prove it

Let $P(n)$ be "$0^n \in S$". We will show that $P(n)$ is true for every integer $n \geq 12$ by strong induction.

**Base Case (n=3, n=5, n=12):** Let us consider $P(3)$ as one of our base cases. By the basis step, we know that $0^3\in S$, thus, $P(3)$ is true. Next, let us consider $P(5)$ as one of our base cases. By the basis step, we know that $0^5\in S$, thus, $P(5)$ is true. Lastly, let us consider $P(12)$. In the basis step, we know that $0^3\in S$ and, in the recursive step, if $0^3, 0^y\in S$ for some integer $y$, then we know $0^3 \cdot 0^y \in S$. If $y=9$, then we would have that $0^{12} \in S$, thus, $P(12)$ is true.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that for some arbitrary integer $k\geq 12$, $P(j)$ is true for all integer $j$ from 12 to $k$.

**Induction Step:** We will show $P(k+1)$ is true or, in other words, $0^{k+1}\in S$. Note that $0^{k+1}=0^k\cdot 0^1$. By our IH, we know $0^k\in S$. Note that $0^3 = 0^1\cdot 0^2$ and since $0^3 \in S$, this implies that $0^1,0^2\in S$. Thus, $0^k\cdot 0^1 = 0^{k+1}\in S$. Therefore, $P(k+1)$ is true.

**Conclusion:** Hence, we can conclude that $P(n)$ is true for every integer $n\geq 12$ by strong induction.

### Explanation

Normally, I would use Structural Induction to prove problems like these. However, Structural Induction is not the best tool for this problem. Structural induction shows $\forall x.\, x \in S \rightarrow P(x)$. Though, in this case, I'm analyzing what the elements of $S$ are in this problem, not proving a predicate holds for all elements of $S$.

This is my first time using strong induction on proofs involving strings, so I feel like I might have written my proof incorrectly or made random leaps of logic that may not make sense in this problem. Any feedback or suggestion would be greatly appreciated in helping me fix this proof.

Comment: Why does $0^3 = 0^1 \cdot 0^2$ imply that $0^1, 0^2 \in S$? The implication doesn't go the other way around. I think the simplest way to prove this is just show the base cases $n = 12, 13, 14$ and then use strong induction for $n \geq 15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $0^3\in S$ does **not** imply that $0^1,0^2\in S$; in fact neither $0^1$ nor $0^2$ is in $S$: elements of $S$ are built up from $0^3$ and $0^5$ by concatenation, so every element of $S$ has length at least $3$.

HINT: Show by direct calculation that $0^{12},0^{13},0^{14}\in S$; that forms the base of your induction. (For instance, $0^{13}=0^5\cdot 0^5\cdot 0^3$.) Then show by induction on $n$ that $0^n\in S$ for all $n\ge 12$. There’s a further hint in the spoiler box.

> Work in sets of $3$ consecutive values of $n$. For instance, use the base to show that $0^{15},0^{16}$, and $0^{17}$ are in $S$. Then use that to show …

You could also use structural induction to show that $0^n\in S$ if and only if there are non-negative integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $n=3k+5\ell$ and then use the same basic induction argument to show that such $k$ and $\ell$ exist whenever $n\ge 12$.

Comment: I see my mistakes now from your suggestions. I'm struggling with the induction step of my proof. I'm just not seeing how I can prove $0^{k+1} \in S$. Can you give me a hint on that? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @ArataKaizaki: Work in sets of three: show that if $0^{3k},0^{3k+1},0^{3k+2}\in S$, then $0^{3(k+1)},0^{3(k+1)+1},0^{3(k+1)+2}\in S$.